# Arduino Obstacle Avoiding Shield controlor motor L293D

Tags: arduino-motor-shield

I am a beginner with Arduino. I wanted to make an Arduino obstacle avoiding. So I ordered last week an L293D Shield Motor Driver and I don't know if what I receive is a good item. The first picture is how it looks on the site and the second picture is what I got.

[image]

[image]

I saw that if you search for this motor you get results for both motors, but they are not the same. And I saw in this tutorial, this person using a motor like mine https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydDvoknlJ9M and then he switched to the motor in the first picture.

Questions: Are these motors the same? Should I request a return? If they are the same, how can I add the pins (as shown in the third picture?

[image]

Again, I am a beginner and I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: Looks exactly the same, except for that some pin headers are missing. You could buy and solder them yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I find this pins from a old kit that I commanded , but they didn't mentioned that it comes without and in the image pins appear .

Comment: do you actually need those pins?

Comment: Yes , I want to make a obstacle avoiding robot and I saw that more people use them

Answer (score 1):

To complete @chrisl answer: Yes you need these pins to make the same robot as in the video. You can order them online and solder them (if you know how to solder and if you have the soldering material). Be careful with soldering ;)

For your information, the pins you circled in red are used to communicate with the Arduino pins A0 to A5, and provide +5V and GND. In the video, they are connected to the ultrasound sensor.

And please clarify what is your `motor`??? Do you mean the `Shield motor driver`? It is not the same. A `shield` is an eletronic board that you plug to your Arduino to do a specific task (control a motor, connect to wifi...). A `motor driver` is the electronic to control the motor. On your pictures, they are mainly the 3 components with 16 legs each.

Comment: Thanks ! It's a shield motor driver

Comment: @AnaNiorba - if this worked for you then you should tick it to indicate that it was the correct answer.